# ZK Textbox content containing <html> tag

Tags: zk

When I put the string '' into a ZK Textbox, that is

```
<textbox value="<html>" />
```

it causes a JavaScript error in the browser

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

and I can see in the developer tools of the browser that the generated JS code is really incomplete:

```js
 zkmx(
[0,'g2JQ_',{dt:'z_y20',cu:'\x2Fdtag',uu:'\x2Fdtag\x2Fzkau',ru:'\x2Fzul\x2Fcomponent\x2Fmenu.zul',style:'width\x3A100\x25\x3B',ct:true},[
...
['zul.inp.Textbox','g2JQp7',{id:'tb',$$0onBlur:true,$$0onSwipe:true,$$0onError:true,$$0onAfterSize:true,$$0onChanging:true,$$1onChange:true,$$1onSelection:true,$$0onFocus:true,width:'500px',style:'font-size:11px;',_value:'
</div>
```

How can I escape the content of the textbox so that I can display any HTML code in the textbox?

I tried

```
Replace '<' with '&gt; but then &gt; is displayed.
```

I also tried

```
<![CDATA[ <html></html>]]>
```

but then it was literally displayed, that is, also the

```
<![CDATA[
```

---

**UPDATE**

It is somehow due to the fact that we have JSPs containing several ZK pages.
And the exact content what causes problem is the closing HTML tag

```
</html>
```

The workaround is the following:

```html
Events.echoEvent("onLater", txtDescription, txtDescription);
   txtDescription.addEventListener("onLater", new EventListener<Event>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
                    txtDescription.setValue("<html>...</html>"); 
               }

   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should get values from your composer or viewmodel, and then this problem doesn't exist.

If you want to do it in the zul, you can make a parameter in zscript like this :

```
<zscript>
    <![CDATA[
        String a = "<html>";
]]>
</zscript>
<textbox value="${a}" />
```

[Here I created a fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1su28e6/1-html-tag) so you can test it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We do it from the composer, but the problem exists! I will test it in a Fiddle, perhaps the problem is due to the fact that our ZUL pages are included in JSPs.

Comment: If you could create the fiddle, that would be very helpful for finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Many time we have saved HTML code in database but when we are going to display that saved value in zk page it show HTML code as well with data .

To resolve this issue we have to use HTML escape there are plenty of way to fix this

You can do it on Java side as well zul page and here is simple way how you can achieve in the zul page

```
<html>
      <![CDATA[
             ${vm.accessYourValue}

      ]]>
</html>
```